# VBPROJ / CSPROJ

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

I'm trying to dig into the XML for a VBPROJ file.  Does anyone know where I can find a good resource that explains the structure and attribute usage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

csproj or vbproj files are nothing but msbuild xml files, which would be consumed by `msbuild.exe`. These xml files adhere to msbuild schema namely: `Microsoft.Build.xsd`.

1. see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dy88c2e.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/msbuild/msbuild-project-file-schema-reference?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN) for msbuild schema reference.
2. Read [Sara Ford's blog post about editing csproj/vbproj files in VS IDE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/saraford/did-you-know-how-to-edit-a-csproj-or-vbproj-project-file-within-the-ide-332)
3. [Where is the MSBuild schema file?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/msbuild/)
4. Another [post on msdn blogs about editing csproj/vbproj files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/msbuild/)

Comment: What about .NET 1.1 the MSBUILD Schema seems to be only 2.0 +

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for this info in order to programatically rip through some vbproj files, you'll probably want to take a look at `Microsoft.Build.Engine.dll`.  Referencing this component gives you access to the MSBuild object model, which can be used to read and manipulate MSBuild files (which csproj and vbproj files are).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this code](http://code.google.com/p/projectpilot/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Flubu/Builds/VSSolutionBrowsing). It contains a simple parser for VS solutions and csproj files. Vbproj shouldn't be much different, so you should be able to extend it for your needs. It's licensed under the MIT license.